# UWP Load GridView with an item alredy selected

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a menu centered on the screen, the menu contains a Grid with a GridView. The content of said GridView is generated via code and when one of the GridViewItems is clicked, an empty Frame loads some information and the menu moves so everything stays centered. I'm handling the motion with "connected animations". The thing is that, with this solution, the clicked GridViewItem goes back to the "normal" state.

Is there a way that I pass the information of which one of the items was clicked so it stays in that state or to load the GridViewItem in a certain state so it appears as if it stayed selected?

This is what I've got so far:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
   <Frame x:Name="ventanaMenuPrincipal"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ConnectedAnimation animation;
    private List<Seccion> Secciones;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Secciones = GestorSecciones.ObtenerSecciones();
        ventanaMenuPrincipal.Navigate(typeof(MenuPrincipal));
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
        animation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().PrepareToAnimate("forwardAnimation", ventanaMenuPrincipal);
        animation.Configuration = new BasicConnectedAnimationConfiguration();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        animation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().GetAnimation("forwardAnimation");
        if (animation != null)
        {
            animation.TryStart(ventanaMenuPrincipal);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().PrepareToAnimate("borderOut", ventanaMenuPrincipal);
    }
}
```

MenuPrincipal.xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ventanaMenuPrincipal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid Width="220" Padding="0,10,0,0">
        <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Secciones}"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemClick="MenuSecciones_Click"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomGridViewItem}"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  Padding="10,10,0,0" 
                  Width="200" 
                  Height="300" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Seccion">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind titulo}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid> <!-- Menú Secciones -->
</StackPanel>
```

MenuPrincipal.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MenuPrincipal : Page
{
    Frame mainframe;
    private ConnectedAnimation animation;
    private List<Seccion> Secciones;
    public MenuPrincipal()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        if (MenuPrincipalState.registrarQuetzalSeleccionado)
        {
            BotonUsuarioNuevo.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        Secciones = GestorSecciones.ObtenerSecciones();
        mainframe = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    }

    #region Clicks

    private void MenuSecciones_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MenuPrincipalState.botonSeleccionado = sender as GridViewItem;
        if (MenuPrincipalState.inicio)
        {
            MenuPrincipalState.inicio = false;
            mainframe.Navigate(typeof(SeccionesPage), null, new SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo());
        }

    }
    #endregion Clicks

    #region Transiciones
    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
        animation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().PrepareToAnimate("forwardAnimation", ventanaMenuPrincipal);
        animation.Configuration = new BasicConnectedAnimationConfiguration();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        animation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().GetAnimation("forwardAnimation");
        if (animation != null)
        {
            animation.TryStart(ventanaMenuPrincipal);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().PrepareToAnimate("borderOut", ventanaMenuPrincipal);
    }
    #endregion Transiciones
}
```

Seccion.cs

```
public class Seccion
{
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public bool activo { get; set; }
    public bool seleccionado { get; set; }

}

public class GestorSecciones
{
    public static List<Seccion> ObtenerSecciones()
    {
        var secciones = new List<Seccion>
        {
            new Seccion {titulo = "PGE", activo = true, seleccionado = false },
            new Seccion {titulo = "PGS", activo = true, seleccionado = false },
            new Seccion {titulo = "DCS", activo = true, seleccionado = false },
            new Seccion {titulo = "SPC", activo = true, seleccionado = false },
            new Seccion {titulo = "DDL", activo = true, seleccionado = false },
            new Seccion {titulo = "PQD", activo = true, seleccionado = false }
        };

        return secciones;
    }
}
```

SeccionesPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="pantallaSecciones" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Frame x:Name="ventanaMenuPrincipal"/>
        <Frame x:Name="info"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

P.S. I've already tried keeping the menu in one Frame and just load the different information in another Frame without changing pages but that way I can't find how to animate the movement of the menu because the width of the "information frame" is variable depending on the GridViewItem selection. Whatever I try, it just pops in into the new position.

Comment: What does "the clicked GridViewItem goes back to the 'normal' state" mean? Do you mean after you used the connected animations, the clicked GridViewItem was canceled the selected state? So you want to stay the selected state? In addition, what have you achieved currently? Can you show some code snippet for us to test?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Exactly. What I want is for it to stay on the selected state. I'll edit the original post with the snippet. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I noticed you click the item and will navigate to another page, when you navigte back, the page content and state is not cached by default, so the selected state won't be stay. You could try to add `this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;` in your constructor of MainPage.xaml.cs, if you do like this, can GridViewItem stay selected?

Comment: Well... It kinda worked. It only stays selected when you return to the page and it messes up with the animations. For one moment the element is duplicated and then it disappears.

Comment: About messing up with the animations, I didn't reproduce this issue, since the code snippet you provided was not complete. So can you provide a simple complete sample that can be reproduced for us to test?